# Unable to compile simple Less file using node-less

Tags: software-installation, compiler

I'm trying to compile a *very* simple [less](http://lesscss.org) file which simply includes Bootstrap:

```
/* application.less: The most awesomely complicated file in the whole world. */
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
```

I'm on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative and I've tried using the `lessc` compiler found in the `node-less` package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install node-less
...done!
$ ( cd /path/of/less/file/ && lessc application.less )
TypeError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined
    at getLocation (/usr/lib/nodejs/less/parser.js:204:34)
    at new LessError (/usr/lib/nodejs/less/parser.js:213:19)
    at Object.toCSS (/usr/lib/nodejs/less/parser.js:379:31)
    at /usr/bin/lessc:103:28
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/less/parser.js:428:40
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/less/parser.js:94:48
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/less/index.js:113:15
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/less/parser.js:428:40
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/less/parser.js:94:48
    at /usr/lib/nodejs/less/index.js:113:15
```

Not easily  deterred, I then tried using the Ruby version of lessc.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge node-less
$ sudo gem install less
...done!
[WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- v8 (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script.rb:9:in `default_context_wrapper'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/java_script.rb:17:in `context_wrapper'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less/loader.rb:10:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less.rb:14:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/less-2.2.2/lib/less.rb:14
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/less-2.2.2/bin/lessc:3
    from /usr/local/bin/lessc:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/lessc:19
```

Come on! Ruby doesn't know how to manage dependencies?! Whatever. Fine.

```
$ sudo gem install therubyracer
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --without-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/build.rb:42:in `build_with_system_libv8': unable to locate libv8. Please see output for details (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:22
    The Ruby Racer requires libv8 ~> 3.11.8
    to be present on your system in order to compile
    and link, but it could not be found.

    In order to resolve this, you will either need to manually
    install an appropriate libv8 and make sure that this
    build process can find it. If you install it into the
    standard system path, then it should just be picked up
    automatically. Otherwise, you'll have to pass some extra
    flags to the build process as a hint.

    If you don't want to bother with all that, there is a
    rubygem that will do all this for you. You can add
    following line to your Gemfile:
        gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'

    We hope that helps, and we apologize, but now we have
    to push the eject button on this install.

    thanks,
    The Mgmt.
```

And I'm done. Is there any *easy* way to get a *working* less compiler installed on my distribution? This is getting ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a lot of help from @Deer Hunter, I got it up and running pretty quickly.

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
$ sudo npm install --global less
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

This side of the screen:

```
 $ node --version
 v.0.8.16
 $ npm --version
 1.1.69
 $ npm install less
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less
 npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/less
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less/-/less-1.3.3.tgz
 npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/less/-/less-1.3.3.tgz
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin
 npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin/-/ycssmin-1.0.1.tgz
 npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin/-/ycssmin-1.0.1.tgz
 less@1.3.3 node_modules/less
 └── ycssmin@1.0.1
 $ ln --symbolic ~/node_modules/.bin/lessc ~/bin/lessc
 $ lessc --version
 lessc 1.3.3 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

The installation works. Could not run your `test.less` file, though (no `bootstrap` installed). Summing it up: why don't you use `npm`? What version of `node` have you got installed?